# Calling a function with an image output to add in map layer

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, function, addlayer

I am trying to estimate the LST using the thermal band (Band 10) of Landsat 8. I have written the final calculation of LST from the brightness temperature under a function. But I am getting trouble calling the function and adding the output using Map.addLayer. The error it is showing is, "b.call is not a function". I'm sure I am writing something wrong while calling the function, but can't identify the mistake as I'm very new to the earth engine platform. The full code is given below:

```
    //Load the study area 
var studyarea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/swadhinakoley/Jhar_Shape');
Map.addLayer(studyarea, {}, 'studyarea');

var district = ee.FeatureCollection('users/swadhinakoley/Dhanbad_geo');

/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image input Landsat 8 SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloudmasked Landsat 8 image
 */
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var L8_display = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000};
var ndvi_palette = 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400, ' + '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301';
function addnd(input) {
  var nd = input.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
  return input.addBands(nd);
}

function addth(input) {
  var th = input.select('B10').multiply(0.1).rename('B_10');
  return input.addBands(th);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2015-02-01', '2015-03-16')
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(studyarea)})
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .map(addnd)
                  .map(addth)
                  ;

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
print(dataset);
Map.setCenter(85.30, 23.34, 8);
Map.addLayer(dataset, visParams);


var ndvi_L8 = dataset.select('ndvi').median();

Map.addLayer(ndvi_L8, {min: -0.1, max: 1, palette: ndvi_palette}, 'NDVI');

//select thermal band 10(with brightness tempereature), no calculation 
var thermal = dataset.select('B10');
var b10Params = {min: 291.918, max: 302.382, palette: ['blue', 
'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(thermal, b10Params, 'thermal');

// find the min and max of NDVI
{
var min = ee.Number(ndvi_L8.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: studyarea,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e11
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min');
var max = ee.Number(ndvi_L8.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: studyarea,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e11
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max');
}

//fractional vegetation
{
var fv =(ndvi_L8.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 
print(fv, 'fv');
Map.addLayer(fv);
}

//Emissivity

var a= ee.Number(0.004);
var b= ee.Number(0.986);
var EM=fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
var imageVisParam3 = {min: 0.9865619146722164, max:0.989699971371314};
Map.addLayer(EM, imageVisParam3,'EMM');

//LST in Celsius Degree bring -273.15
//NB: In Kelvin don't bring -273.15

 function addtemp(input) {

var temp = input.expression(
'(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
 'Tb': thermal.select('B10'),
'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
});

return temp;
}

var LST = addtemp;
print(LST, 'LST');
Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 20.569706944223423, max:29.328077233404645, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
 ]},'LST');


// Export the NDVI to drive

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_L8,
  description: 'NDVI_Dhanbad',
  scale: 30,
  region: district
});

// Export the LST to drive

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: LST,
  description: 'LST_Dhanbad',
  scale: 30,
  region: district
});
```

The part I'm getting the error is as below:

```
    function addtemp(input) {

var temp = input.expression(
'(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
 'Tb': thermal.select('B10'),
'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
});

return temp;
}

var LST = addtemp;

print(LST, 'LST');

Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 20.569706944223423, max:29.328077233404645, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
 ]},'LST');
```

Please help me to know the correct syntax for calling the function.

Comment: Your link does not work. Please click on the 'Get Link' button and share that link.

Comment: I have edited my post with the full code. Please see above.

Comment: And would you please make your assets public too? Check the anyone can read box

Comment: Done so. Is it accessible now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so a couple things here. You want to calculate the LST for each image, so you have to map the calculation over each image in the imagecollection. This can be done by using the .map function. Also, mind you that there can be a scaling factor in the ImageCollection you are using, which I added to the code:

```
//Load the study area 
var studyarea = ee.FeatureCollection('users/swadhinakoley/Jhar_Shape');
Map.addLayer(studyarea, {}, 'studyarea');

var district = ee.FeatureCollection('users/swadhinakoley/Dhanbad_geo');

/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image input Landsat 8 SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloudmasked Landsat 8 image
 */
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var L8_display = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000};
var ndvi_palette = 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400, ' + '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301';
function addnd(input) {
  var nd = input.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
  return input.addBands(nd);
}

function addth(input) {
  var th = input.select('B10').multiply(0.1).rename('B_10');
  return input.addBands(th);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2015-02-01', '2015-03-16')
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(studyarea)})
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .map(addnd)
                  .map(addth)
                  ;

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
print(dataset.limit(20));
Map.setCenter(85.30, 23.34, 8);
Map.addLayer(dataset, visParams);


var ndvi_L8 = dataset.select('ndvi').median();
var min = ee.Number(ndvi_L8.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: studyarea,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e11
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min');
var max = ee.Number(ndvi_L8.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: studyarea,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e11
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max');

//fractional vegetation
var fv =(ndvi_L8.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 
print(fv, 'fv');
Map.addLayer(ndvi_L8, {min: -0.1, max: 1, palette: ndvi_palette}, 'NDVI');

var a= ee.Number(0.004);
var b= ee.Number(0.986);
var EM=fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
  
var LST = dataset.map(function(image){
  var thermal = image.select('B10').multiply(0.1) // Check the product: a scale factor of 0.1 is added
  var temp = image.expression(
  '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
   'Tb': thermal,
  'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
  }).rename('temp');
  return image.addBands([EM, temp])
  })

print(LST.limit(10), 'LST')
Map.addLayer(LST.median().select('temp'), {min: 20.569706944223423, max:29.328077233404645, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
 ]},'LST');


// Export the NDVI to drive

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_L8,
  description: 'NDVI_Dhanbad',
  scale: 30,
  region: district
});

// Export the LST to drive

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: LST.median(),
  description: 'LST_Dhanbad',
  scale: 30,
  region: district
});
```

Comment: Is this answering your question?

Comment: Thanks for the modified code. Actually, I was trying to resolve the issue myself by modifying the code multiple ways, before looking at this solution. Anyway, this helped. Thanks again.

Comment: If the answer is useful, please give the upvote. If there are still problems, please keep on asking questions

Comment: I tried to. But I guess I don't have enough points to do so. It declined to take my vote.

Comment: You can still check it as an useful answer I believe. But if not, no worries